# Как получить количество совпадений array_key_exists?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как получит количество совпадений при сравнении массивов?

```
$rows = $cost->getRows();
    $orders = $results->getRows();

    $tmp = array_column($rows, 1, 0);
    foreach($orders as &$v){
         if(array_key_exists($v[3], $tmp)){
             $v[] = $tmp[$v[3]];
         }
    }
```

Нужно что было на выходе так:

```
$v[] = $tmp[$v[3]] / $key_exists;
```

Спасибо.

Comment: без контекста вашего предыдущего примера тут никто ничего не поймет. Так что приведите пример входных данных и желаемого результата. По факту вам надо первым циклом посчитать количество совпадений. а потом вторым уже добавлять.

Comment: и кстати, делить надо на общее число совпадение, или число совпадений текущего значения?

Comment: array_key_exists — Проверяет, присутствует ли в массиве указанный ключ или индекс. Именно ключ, а Вам скорее всего нужно значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если за основу взять пример ваших данных из [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/725613/1)

```
$orders = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 1],
    ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 2],
    ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 3],
    ['a4', 'b4', 'c4', 5],
    ['a5', 'b5', 'c5', 5],
];

$rows = [ [1, 1000], [2 , 2000],  [5,5000]];
```

то в целом, общее число совпадений значений 3-го столбца первого массива `$orders` и 0-го столбца `$rows` можно получить как

```
$count = count(array_intersect(array_column($orders, 3), array_column($rows, 0)));
```

для данного примера результат будет равен `4`.

Где результатом работы функции пересчения массивов `array_intersect` будет

```
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 5
)
```

А если требуется посчитать число совпадений для каждого элемента, то используя функцию `array_count_values` можно получить следующий результат:

```
Array (
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [5] => 2
)
```

Если же потребуется число совпадений без повторов, то

```
count(array_unique(array_intersect(...))
```

вернет результат `3`.